# How do I get the row and column of a table with indices.

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a table which has x columns where indexes are ordered horizontally:

```
 0  1  2  3
 4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11
12 13 14
```

and a table with x rows where the indexes are ordered vertically:

```
 0  5 10 15
 1  6 11 16
 2  7 12
 3  8 13
 4  9 14
```

With which formulas could I get the row and column number of a certain index in these two cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first table, `row = num / x` and `col = num % x`.

For the second table, the indices are swapped: `row = num % x` and `col = num / x`.

Here, `/` stands for integer division (rounded down) and `%` for taking the remainder of that division.